# create numpy array by appending a number to another numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

This supposedly simple task is driving me a bit mad.
Say you want to create an array by concatenating an integer to another array:

```
import numpy as np

a = 4
b = np.array([1, 10, 24, 12])
A = np.array(a, b)
```

gives me `TypeError: data type not understood`. Which I understand because I'm mixing an integer with a list. Now if I do `A = np.array([a], b)` I get the same result, if I get `A = np.array([a] + b)` I don't get the expected result.
Also, I tried `A = np.array([a, *b])` with `SyntaxError: can use starred expression only as assignment target`.
How's the proper way to do this?

Comment: The 1st argument to `np.array` is the object (list) that's being converted.  the 2nd argument is the `dtype`.  `b` is not a valid `dtype`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with using [`np.append`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)?:

```
In [20]:

a = 4
b = np.array([1, 10, 24, 12])
np.append(a,b)

Out[20]:
array([ 4,  1, 10, 24, 12])
```

Comment: In case it isn't clear - `append` returns a new array.  It doesn't change `a`.  It is an alternative way of using `concatenate`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the concatenate function to do this

```
A = np.concatenate(([a], b))
```

For your case, I think using `append` is "better" since it is less error prone as it accepts scalars as well, (as my own mistake clearly shows!) and (arguably) slightly more readable.

Comment: This generates `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated`

Comment: ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated

Comment: Good catch. I forgot the `[]` to make the first variable a list and not a scalar.

Comment: Also, I think `append` is probably a better answer. But knowing about `concatenate` might be useful if you have multiple smaller arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj, What kind of abuse are you thinking of that would have been better solved by e.g. concatenate?

Comment: 2 uses come to mind - assuming it is an inplace function like the list append, and using it repeatedly in a loop, again like the list method.

Comment: I see your point, but since it is a module function, and not a member function of `numpy.array` I think it's different enough from `list.append` to still work fine. For the loop example, is it actually better to append the result to a ordinary list, and then append that to the array?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `hstack` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
In [194]: a = 4
In [195]: b = np.array([1, 10, 24, 12])
In [196]: np.hstack((a,b))
Out[196]: array([ 4,  1, 10, 24, 12])
```

hstack has the advantage that it can concatenate as many arrays/lists as you want (e.g. `np.hstack((a, b, a, b, [0, 2, 4, 6, 8])`))

Comment: I tried `np.hstack((a,b)) == np.append(a,b)` to find out whether the results are identical, but it gave me an array with five Trues, i.e., it apparently only compared the contents. I get the same five Trues array for `np.hstack((a,b)) == [4,1,10,24,12]`, even though the results are different types. Is there a way to "fully" compare the hstack and append results?

Comment: @StefanPochmann That is the normal behaviour for numpy arrays. Two arrays are equal if all items are equal. To test equality for numpy arrays, use `all` => `all(np.hstack((a, b)) == np.append(a, b))` returns True

Comment: @StefanPochmann you can also use `np.array_equal()` to determine whether two arrays are equal or not.

Comment: Thanks, though both of those also say True when I compare with the Python list. Rather disappointing if there's no way to really check it other than additionally checking type/dtype/whatever.

Comment: Question of opinion but I think that's what makes it nice ... if it looks, quacks and walks like a duck, ... also depends why you need to check the equality.

Comment: Like I said, I wanted to find out whether hstack and append really produce identical results. Their results "look" equal at simple sight and they pass those equality tests, but how do I know they don't subtly differ inside? I guess I should just learn numpy and maybe then it'll bother me as little as `3 == 3.0` does now.

Comment: fair enough ... in this case, the two objects are equal if they have the same type, the same shape and the same items ... `np.array_equal()` tests for the last two conditions ... you'd need to add the type check to know if the results are identical (in this case, they are).

Comment: `np.allclose(a,b)` is my preferred way of comparing arrays.  It handles the case of floats better.   `hstack` and `append` are both coded in Python, so you can study the code.  Both end up using the compiled `concatenate`.

Comment: @hpaulj Ugh, right now I'm even less keen on studying the code than I am on studying the docs, so I'll just trust you guys :-). Thanks for the advice.